# Select SUM from Result with Limit in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sum

I am the beginner of codeigniter.
I have a query like this, I want to use this query in codeigniter

```
SELECT sum(price) 
FROM (SELECT price
      FROM items
      ORDER BY price DESC
      LIMIT 3
) AS subquery;
```

I have did

```
$this->db->select('SUM(price)');
$this->db->select('price');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->order_by('price desc');
$this->db->limit(3);
$this->db->get();
```

This gives output like this

```
SELECT sum(price), price
      FROM items
      ORDER BY price DESC
      LIMIT 3;
```

What Can I do?

Comment: is ur raw query works fine ?

Comment: My raw query works well

Comment: you can use [CodeIgniter-Subqueries](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries) . if you are using CI3 take a look at [Query grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20record#id6)

Answer (score 10):

Use like this

```
$this->db->select_sum('price');
$this->db->select('price');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->order_by('price desc');
$this->db->limit(3);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: I didn't get expected output

Comment: what result you want?

Comment: when I try your query it will gives the output like this  `SELECT sum(price), price
      FROM items
      ORDER BY price DESC
      LIMIT 3;`

Answer (score 5):

you can use a query like this

```
$this->db->select_sum('price');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->order_by('price desc');
$this->db->limit(3);
$this->db->get();
```

If you want to put data into an array then:

```
 $data=$this->db
    ->select_sum('price')
    ->from('items')
     ->order_by('price desc')
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();
return $data->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

make it simple if your query is working fine.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT sum(price) FROM (SELECT price FROM items ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS subquery');
print_r($query->result_array());
```

Comment: Actually this is not my query,  I have a big table with join in my module. I have just asked a simple item. If I try your query It'll take 50 lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function advanceSalary($id) {
        if ($id) {
            $this->db->select('salaryLaser.*');
            //$this->db->select_sum('salaryLaser.credit');
            $this->db->select('SUM(salaryLaser.credit) as creditTotal');
            $this->db->select('SUM(salaryLaser.debit) as debitTotal');
            $this->db->from($this->salaryLaser);
            $this->db->where('salaryLaser.employeeId', $id);
            $this->db->where('salaryLaser.employeeRole', '1');
            $advance = $this->db->get();
            if ($advance->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $advance->row();
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this to fix it:

```
 /**
  * [total_currency description]
  * @param  [type] $column_name [description]
  * @param  [type] $where       [description]
  * @param  [type] $table_name  [description]
  * @return [type]              [description]
  */

function total_count($column_name,  $where, $table_name)
{
   $this->db2->select_sum($column_name);
    // If Where is not NULL
    if(!empty($where) && count($where) > 0 )
    {
       $this->db2->where($where);
    }

      $this->db2->from($table_name);
        // Return Count Column
return $this->db2->get()->row($column_name);//table_name array sub 0




 }
```